# How to use jwt in koa2 & nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt, koa

I have a page written in nodejs and koa, and I'm a little confused about JWT, please check following code.

```
'use strict';
const Router = require("koa-router");
const router = new Router({prefix: '/login'});
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const jwtkey = "123456";
router
    .get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
        await ctx.render("login", {
            
        });
    })
    .post('/', async (ctx, next) => {
        try {
            let email = ctx.request.body.email || "";
            let password = ctx.request.body.password || "";
            //check user
            if (islogin) {
                let payload = {
                    email: email,
                    password: sha1(password).toString()
                }
                let token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtkey, {expiresIn: '3h'});
                ctx.body = {"error": false, "msg": token};
            } else {
                throw "Wrong";
            }
        } catch (e) {
            ctx.body = {error:true, msg: e instanceof Error ? e.message : e};
        }
    })
module.exports = router;
```

I want to implement that when accessing the login page, if the token generated by jwt exists on the server side and is correct, then `console.log("logined")`，if not,  show the login page.

```
.get('/', async (ctx, next) => {
  //how to verify the token?
  if(token) {
     console.log("logined");
  } else {
    await ctx.render("login", {
            
    });
  }
})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After generating the token you should set that token in user's browser as cookie or some other way,

Then while requesting / page check for the token and verify the validity

```
var decoded = jwt.verify(token, key);
```